# Hide / show table with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a little problem to hide and show table. I tred this, I haven't error in console but it does'nt work. Maybe I forget something wrong or make a mistake.

I saw the data inside the code but it does'nt appear when I click on the link.

Thank you

```
      $i = 0;

      foreach($option_attributes_name as $value) {
         $content .= '    <li class="col-md-12"><a onclick="showTabOption' . $i .'" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tooltip" data-target="#section_ProductsAttributesNewApp_content" href="' . OSCOM::link('index.php?A&Catalog\Products&Edit&cPath=' . $_GET['cPath'] . '&pID=' .  $_GET['pID'] . '#tab-option' . $i) . '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> ' . $value['name'] . '</a></li>';
        //        $i++;
        $t++;
      }

      $Qoption = $this->app->db->prepare('select option_id, type
                                          from :table_test_products_options_attributes');
      $Qoption->execute();

      $i =0;
      while ($Qoption->fetch()) {

      $content .= '<div id="tab-option' . $i . '" style="display:none;">';
      $content .= '<h4>' . $Qoption->value('type') . '</h4>';
      $content .= '<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    </table>
                    </div>
                ';
        $content .= '
<script type="text/javascript"><!--   
    function showTabOption' . $i . '() {
      $("a[href=\'#tab-option' .$i . '\']").parent().remove();
      $(\'#tab-option'. $i . '\').remove(); 
      $(\'#option a:first\').div(\'show\');
    }
//--></script>  
        ';
        $i++;
      }
```

Comment: "it does'nt work" is never a good description of a problem. Try to be more specific.

Comment: From what I can see it seems your tables are always empty?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I saw the data inside the code but it does'nt appear when I try to click on the link.

Comment: Does the final rendered code ( source code ) look ok? Why not have a single function to handle these requests rather than multiple in a loop?

Comment: @RamRaider : yes the code source is correct, the console does'nt show error. Just when I click on the link, the element is not displayed; i don't know if my script is correct

Comment: If you simplify your question, just show the table html, and the javascript, then we can try it ourselves, see what happens, and explain why.

Comment: You should never put `script` output inside of a `while` php loop like that. Make one js function that can handle all elements. Especially since you are using jquery, this is far much easier using a class selector for event handling. And get rid of the `<!-- //-->`. And dont bother with `onclick` if you are using jquery as well.

Comment: @IncredibleHat : How would you do, js is not a cup of thea for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can settle a few issues first by adjusting how you are doing things with the js and jquery use.

1) Setting up the elements you will click with just a `class`, and `data-tableid`:

```
$content .= '<li class="col-md-12"><a class="showTabOption nav-link" data-tableid="'. $i .'" ... etc etc ...</a>';
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2) Fix this in your first loop: Change `$t++;` to `$i++;`.

3) You do not need to adjust the table builds (the ones from the `while` loop):

```
$content .= '<div id="tab-option'. $i .'" style="display:none;">';// this is ok
```

4) Then adjust your SINGLE javascript function. Have it output OUTSIDE of the `while` loop (since this must only be done once):

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".showTabOption").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();                    // stop the a href from firing off
        var tableid = $(this).data('tableid'); // the table in question
        $(this).parent().remove();             // remove what you clicked?
        $("#tab-option"+ tableid ).show();     // show your options table
    });
});
</script>
```

This should get you rolling on making that table (the div surrounding it) show up when you click one of those links. Of course it looks like you have much more going on in there, table rows, something with the href link value, and the sort, but you only asked about showing the table div.

---

**TL;DR:** Full example of your example code adjusted:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($option_attributes_name as $value) {
        $content .= '<li class="col-md-12"><a class="showTabOption nav-link" data-tableid="'. $i .'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-target="#section_ProductsAttributesNewApp_content" href="'. OSCOM::link('index.php?A&Catalog\Products&Edit&cPath='. $_GET['cPath'] .'&pID='.  $_GET['pID'] .'#tab-option'. $i) .'"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> '. $value['name'] .'</a></li>';
        $i++;
    }
    $Qoption = $this->app->db->prepare('select option_id, type
                                        from :table_test_products_options_attributes');
    $Qoption->execute();
    $i = 0;
    while ($Qoption->fetch()) {
        $content .= '<div id="tab-option'. $i .'" style="display:none;">';
        $content .= '<h4>'. $Qoption->value('type') .'</h4>';
        $content .= '<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
        // table tr rows go here
        $content .= '</table>';
        $content .= '</div>';
        $i++;
    }
?>

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".showTabOption").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();                    // stop the a href from firing off
        var tableid = $(this).data('tableid'); // the table in question
        $(this).parent().remove();             // remove what you clicked?
        $("#tab-option"+ tableid ).show();     // show your options table
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Works in part
About the loop foreach, when I click on the link, the menu link diseapear.
About the table, when I click on the menu, I saw the table (the link diseapear) and when I reclick another link, the 2nd link diseapear and there is 2 table (first click and second click).
The big problem is it's impossible to click another time  menu link because the menu diseapear.
You can test on the link : https://jsfiddle.net/3mwcdq3c/4/

Comment: Then remove this `$(this).parent().remove();`. I left that in there because your code had to remove the link you click. I wasn't sure why, but if its causing a problem, then remove that line.

Comment: In fact, it may be more user friendly if you did something like `$(this).parent().addClass('table-opened');` Then make a class for that, that changes the color or style of the menu item to denote that its been opened. Options are endless when it comes to jquery and css fun stuff :)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/3mwcdq3c/4 : add you proposition; could you look ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3mwcdq3c/9/ Thats the change I mentioned. And this shows a way you can 'toggle' your tables: http://jsfiddle.net/3mwcdq3c/10/

Comment: Thank you for your help. +1 . jsfiddle.net/3mwcdq3c/10 is better